# How to configure msmtp with Amazon SES?

Tags: php, amazon-ses, msmtp

Amazon has instructions for postfix and sendmail, but not [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/) (simple SMTP client), so adding them here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install [msmtp](https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html) (ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install msmtp msmtp-mta
```

Configure it (`sudo nano /etc/msmtprc`):

```
defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
syslog on

account default
host email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
port 587
auth on
user YOUR_AMAZON_SES_SMTP_USERNAME
password YOUR_AMAZON_SES_SMTP_PASSWORD
from YOUR_AMAZON_SES_VERIFIED_SENDER
```

Use it. You don't need to set up PHP with the server info; the default configuration will pass messages to sendmail, and you're good to go.

```
<?php

mail("user@example.com", "some subject", "some message");

?>
```

If you don't use PHP, you can test on the command line:

```
$ sendmail test-recipient@example.com
Subject: test subject

This is a test message!
^D
```

(The `^D` means type control-D to stop typing the message and send it.)

Comment: With Amazon SES, don't forget to verify the sender domain (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html) and enable production SES mode, or you won't be able to send to arbitrary addrs.

Comment: If you enable `logfile`, then sending mail will fail if the current user doesn't have write access to the log file. It's better to use `syslog on` instead, so that the log messages can be routed by syslog from any user, to wherever you please.